# Коллекция из БД в MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть как я думаю стандартный подход к получению данных из БД.

```
public static class Core
{
public static IList<string> GetItems() => 
          (new BusinessContext()).GetAll<...>().Where(...).ToList();    
...
}
```

Во ViewModel имеем следующее:

```
private IList<string> _items;
public ICollectionView ItemsCollection {get; set;}

public void CONSTRUCTOR()
{
   _items = new List<string>();
   _items = Core.GetItems();
   ItemsCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_items);
   ItemsCollection.Refresh();
}
```

Привязываем, и получаем список из БД в нашей View.

Однако, если сделать вот-так:

```
private string _foo;
public string Foo
{
  get { return _foo;}
  set { _foo = value; 
        NotifyProppertyChange();
        if (_foo != null)
        {
         _items.Clear();
         _items = Core.GetItems();
          ItemsCollection.Refresh();
        }
     }
}
```

Ничего во вью, не отображается, пока не заменим `_items = Core.GetItems();` на

```
foreach( string item in Core.GetItems()) _items.Add(item);
```

Вопрос: почему в конструкторе срабатывает, а тут нет?

Comment: Вызовайте `NotifyProppertyChange();` не до обновления коллекции, а после, т.е. после вашего `if (_foo != null)`

Comment: @Bulson , с Foo, все в порядке, оно обновляется, а вот вновь загруженные данные в коллекцию не отображаются.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы в VM используете типы наподобие `CollectionView`. Это чисто вьюшные типы, которые вам не должны быть интересны.

Для того, чтобы обновление коллекции подхватывалось, вы должны использовать в VM коллекцию, реализующую `INotifyCollectionChanged` (не путайте с `INotifyPropertyChanged`). Например, `ObservableCollection<string>` для вашего случая.

Comment: а сортировка, фильтрация и группировка коллекции... придётся тогда опять что-то дополнительно накручивать?

Comment: @MaximK: Сортировка и всё такое — это по идее вьюшная задача. Вот на том уровне и надо работать с `CollectionView`. Но привязка должна быть к `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: А если надо сохранять сортировку при перезапуске - то это всё ещё вьюшная задача?

Comment: @Monk: Тогда критерии сортировки — VM-задача, а сама сортировка — вьюшная. Невьюшной она станет если, например, сортировка и разбиение на страницы будет выполняться в базе.